# What is the average width of the Via Dolorosa?

Tags: crucifixion

What is the average width of the Via Dolorosa?

The intention is to reason the maximum length of the "stau·rós" or "xý·lon" Jesus would have carried (not dragged) - as he walked to Golgatha.

Answer (score 2):

The *average* of anything is generally useless when one considers specific parts. (E.g. when Bill Gates enters a room, the average person there is a multi-millionaire.)

What you want is the *narrowest* width.  But even that is useless: if there were some especially narrow part, the object could have been turned to the vertical plane to get through.

(Irreverent memories of Jerry Lewis trying to carry a long object sideways through a doorway.)

Comment: I gotta get in a room with Bill Gates :)